# Using %s and sprintf is not giving the expected outcome

Tags: c++

This is probably a simple question but I have tried everything and am at a total loss.

```
sprintf(&szDevCapEntry[strlen(szDevCapEntry)], ",%s:%0d", (LPCSTR)szAnalogP, szAnalogChannels);
```

The entry should add `AL:1000` but it adds `A:1000` and I have no idea why. `szAnalogP` is definitely AL. Anyone any ideas?

EDIT: MY function:

```
extern "C" UINT __stdcall WriteDriverEntry(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
UINT er = ERROR_SUCCESS;
CString m_DevicePrintName, m_nDeviceNumber, m_DeviceName;
LPWSTR szDevicePrintName= NULL, szDeviceNum = NULL, szValueBuf = NULL, szAnalogP = NULL, szDigitalP = NULL, szAnalogOP = NULL, szDigitalOP = NULL;
LPWSTR szDiagnosticP = NULL, szCounterP;
CHAR    szDevCapEntry[256], szBuffer[MAX_PATH];
int Index, szAnalogChannels, szDigitalChannels, szAnalogOChannels, szDigitalOChannels, szDiagnosticChannels, szCounterChannels;

hr = WcaInitialize(hInstall, "WriteDriverEntry");
ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to initialize");

WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Initialized.");

hr = WcaGetProperty(L"COMPORTNUMBER", &szDeviceNum);
ExitOnFailure(hr, "failed to get comport number");
m_nDeviceNumber = szDeviceNum;

hr = WcaGetProperty(L"DEVICEPRINTNAME", &szDevicePrintName);
ExitOnFailure(hr, "failed to get device print name");
m_DevicePrintName = szDevicePrintName;

hr = WcaGetProperty(L"DEVICENAME",&szValueBuf);
ExitOnFailure(hr, "failed to get device name");
m_DeviceName = szValueBuf;

wsprintf(szDevCapEntry, "%s,%s,%s", (LPCSTR)m_DeviceName, m_nDeviceNumber, (LPCSTR)m_DevicePrintName);

hr = WcaGetProperty(L"ANALOGPREFIX",&szAnalogP);
hr = WcaGetIntProperty(L"ANALOGCHANNELS",&szAnalogChannels);

if (szAnalogChannels != 0 )
{
    WcaSetProperty(L"TEST", szAnalogP);
    sprintf(&szDevCapEntry[strlen(szDevCapEntry)], ",%s:%0d", (LPCSTR)szAnalogP, szAnalogChannels);
    WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD,  szDevCapEntry);
}

    if (!UpdateCapEntry(szDevCapEntry))
    return -1;

LExit:

er = SUCCEEDED(hr) ? ERROR_SUCCESS : ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
return WcaFinalize(er);
}
```

I have different variations such as %.2s so that it would display two characters but I only get one. I am sorry if this a too broad a question but I am a beginner and cannot figure this out. I thought maybe converting the variable to a char might work but it gave me the same outcome.

Comment: Either SSCCE fast or it will be closed as too localized

Comment: How is `szAnalogP` declared? How do you assign to it? Have you checked in a debugger that is actually is what you expect it to be?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Yes I set a property just before using the variable and it tells me that it is `AL`.

Comment: `sprintf` is not C++!

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: The C++ standard disagrees with you.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It's a C-ism, and shouldn't be used. Use a `ostringstream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you show.

One thing that does look odd is that you have to explicitly cast `szAnalogP` to `LPCSTR`. This suggests that it's some other type. I wonder if it could be a Unicode C string that you're interpreting is an ASCII string, or something along those lines?

Comment: Hi, Thanks it is a `LPWSTR` that was a trial and error sort of mistake i forgot to take out again.

Comment: @NatalieCarr: That's exactly the problem then.

Comment: With or without it gives me the same outcome.

Comment: @NatalieCarr: Try `%S` instead of `%s`.

Comment: Thats solved my problem (phew) Can you explain the difference to me please so that I can learn from my mistakes? Thanks